# Conditionally add json file into Main json file in jq 1.5

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with just one object as below. Am calling it Auth.json

```
{ 
    "name": "Authorization",
    "description": "This parameter represents the Authorization token obtained from the OKTA Authorization server. It is the Bearer token provided to authorize the consumer. Usage Authorization : Bearer token",
     "in": "header",
     "required": true,
     "type": "string"
}
```

I need to add the above json file value into the below json, only if the below path
`.paths.<any method that starts with />.get.parameters` does not have that object already. 
If it exists that object needs to be removed and the contents of the above Auth.json needs to be added.
I have jq 1.5 and do have access on the system to update the jq initialization file, so could not use walk function which would've made this simpler.

Main.json

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
    "paths": {
    "/agents/delta": {
      "get": {
        "description": "lorem ipsum doram",
        "operationId": "getagentdelta",
        "summary": "GetAgentDelta",
        "tags": [
          "Agents"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "since",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Format - date-time (as date-time in RFC3339). The time from which you need changes from. You should use the format emitted by Date's toJSON method (for example, 2017-04-23T18:25:43.511Z). If a timestamp older than a week is passed, a business rule violation will be thrown which will require the client to change the from date. As a best-practice, for a subsequent call to this method, send the timestamp when you <b>started</b> the previous delta call (instead of when you completed processing the response or the max of the lastUpdateOn timestamps of the returned records). This will ensure that you do not miss any changes that occurred while you are processing the response from this method",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

I tried the below command, but it is adding it recursively within all objects of the path in the Main.json.

```
jq --slurpfile newval Auth.json '.paths | .. | .get.parameters += $newval' Main.json > test.json
```

How can I achieve the above using jq 1.5?

Comment: Could someone please explain why this question has been downvoted, I have gone through many posts here, and tried objects in the above command, and tried map and select commands too, but I either get errors or no output.

Comment: I upvoted the question, seems a really good effort made!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it almost right, but missing the part to identify those objects whose name contains `/`. You can use `startswith()` on the keyname

```
jq --slurpfile auth Auth.json '
    .paths |= with_entries( 
        if .key|startswith("/") 
        then
           .value.get.parameters |= $auth  
        else 
           . end
    )' Main.json
```

Additionally, if you would like to compare if `.parameters` object does not already contain the Authentication object, change your if condition to

```
if (.key|startswith("/")) and (.value.get.parameters[] != $auth)
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a million! I was breaking my head since 3 days now on this. I just changed the command to this to get the completed json file `jq --slurpfile auth Auth.json ' .paths |= with_entries(  if .key|startswith("/")  then  .value.get.parameters += $auth  else  . end )' Main.json`

Comment: @Inian - Your proposed solution does not check whether the array already includes the authorization object.

Comment: Since $auth is an array, you'd want to check `.value.get.parameters !=  $auth[]` (or `all(.value.get.parameters[]; . != $auth[0])`).  Why the OP wants `+= $auth` is a bit of a mystery ...

Comment: @peak , @Inian Thanks for your valuable inputs. If I use the command like this `.value.get.parameters |= $auth`, the object $auth is the only object getting added within the parameters array. Hence I used `+=` instead, which makes the object get added without changing the original structure of the json. Apologies if I was not clear earlier.

Comment: @Inian Am trying to refine the command to get the object Authorization added, under any method starting with / and also one more level down, within the parameter array. So I tried this `jq --slurpfile auth auth.json ' .paths |= with_entries(  if (.key|startswith("/")) and (.value | .. | .parameters[]?.name != "Authorization") then  .value| .. |.parameters? += $auth  else  . end )' test.json` But I get the error `jq: error (at test.json:3027): object ({"name":"si...) and array ([{"name":"A...) cannot be added`

Comment: This question is only for the scope asked and its over. If you have a new question, post a separate question with details @AK123

Comment: @Inian Ok. I post as a new question with details